# ArrayList is filled with random numbers, weirdly causing foreach to draw from a random index

Tags: java, random, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm still fairly new to Java and have recently started dabbling a bit with ArrayList and LinkedList. While programming a simple lottery-algorithm, I have encountered a problem I don't quite understand.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Millionaire 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> lottery = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Random draw = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
        {
            lottery.add(draw.nextInt(50));
        }

        for (int m : lottery)
        {
            System.out.println(lottery.get(m));
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling goes without a hitch, but running the program pretty much always causes an OutOfBoundsExeption. It seems that the printing loop tries to use the content of the Arraylist as the indexes it tries to access, so that any entry larger than 6 causes the program to crash. Could anybody help my understand why it does that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, `m` *is* the lottery number, not an index. So if your ArrayList were:

```
30,11,2,4,8,17
```

Then your for-loop would first fetch the first value (30), and attempt to get the lottery value at index 30 (causing your exception).

You can simply change your second for-loop to do this:

```
System.out.println(m);
```

Alternatively, if you want to get the value at index m, then you should change your for-loop to the following:

```
int c = lottery.size();

for(int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    System.out.println(lottery.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Basically just a misunderstanding on how the loop works.

Comment: @qwr - Good catch; I had meant that! The perils of coding outside of an IDE ;)

Comment: @Mvin - Yeah, but no worries! You'll catch on soon enough, and Java's syntax for `for-loops` and `foreach-loops` _is_ rather confusing at first, and when to use each. Personally, I'm a fan of PHP's `foreach($array as $element) {}`, but that's a discussion for another time.

Answer (score 1):

**Bearing that in mind:** `m` in you for loop is the value in  `ArrayList<Integer>`, it is not the index of the List `ArrayList<Integer>`. `m` ranges [0, 50). You are trying to generate 6 int random numbers, if the random number is generated greater than 6, then, with such random numbers, it will cause Exception : **OutOfBoundsExeption** with your for-loop below:

```
    for (int m : lottery)
    {
        System.out.println(lottery.get(m));
    }
```

There are 2 ways for you to avoid the Exception.

**Way#1:**

Change

```
    for (int m : lottery)
    {
        System.out.println(lottery.get(m));
    }
```

To

```
    for (int m : lottery)
    {
        System.out.println(m);
    }
```

**Way#2**

Change

```
    for (int m : lottery)
    {
        System.out.println(lottery.get(m));
    }
```

To

```
    for(int i=0; i < lottery.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println(lottery.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the for cycle

```
for (int m : lottery)
```

iterates over the values of the `lottery` array. So the `m` has 6 random values. You assumed that `m` will be an index value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> lottery = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random draw = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        lottery.add(draw.nextInt(50));
        System.out.println(lottery.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your last loop you already have the random integer m. You dont need to to the lottery.get(...) part.